# SmartGWT DataSource.destroy() and recreation

Tags: null, datasource, smartgwt, destroy

I have the following DataSource class:

```
public class MyDataSource extends DataSource {

private static MyDataSource instance;
private static final String COLUMN_ONE = "One";
private static final String COLUMN_TWO = "Two";

public static MyDataSource getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MyDataSource("ID");
    }
    return instance;
}

private MyDataSource(String id) {
    setDataProtocol(DSProtocol.CLIENTCUSTOM);
    setDataFormat(DSDataFormat.CUSTOM);
    setClientOnly(false);
    constructDataSource(id);
}

private void constructDataSource(String id) {
    setID(id);
    DataSourceTextField one = new DataSourceTextField(COLUMN_ONE);
    DataSourceTextField two= new DataSourceTextField(COLUMN_TWO);
    setFields(one, two);
}

// and the rest of the class
```

}

I create an instance of this class from another class via `MyDataSource ds = MyDataSource.getInstance();` and upon some actions, I need to destroy and recreate it. I do `ds.destroy(); ds = MyDataSource.getInstance();` but I noticed that `instance` is not null after the destruction, so basically the second call to `MyDataSource.getInstance();` is returning the old object to me. How can I destroy this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datasource follows the singleton pattern.  You are not "creating an instance of this class" since the static `getInstance` method always return the same instance. I'm not sure how `destroy()` is implemented in the `com.smartgwt.client.core.BaseClass` but if you want to destroy your datasource, maybe you should override this method and set `instance` to `null`. This will enforce the creation of a new instance in the `getInstance` method.